# How to create a Javascript/JSON script which changes the font of a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension which changes fonts in order to make websites look nicer.
For example, it changes Comic Sans to Helvetica.

My code so far goes like this:

**Index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

**Main.css**

```css
.some-font { font-family:"Comic Sans MS", "Chalkboard", cursive; }
.another-font { font-family: Helvetica, Sans-Serif; }
```

**Main.js**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(‘h1’).removeClass(‘some-font’).addClass(‘another-font’);// all custom jQuery will go here
});
```

**Mainifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Chrome Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Changes Fonts to make websites/mails look beter",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "index.html"
  },
  "incognito": "split",
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon.png"
    }

}
```

When I tried this in my mail it didn't work. Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to declare main.js and css as a content script in manifest.json to make it run on web pages automatically. And you can simply [substitute local src for @font-family](https://gist.github.com/Hexcles/6325659) in your css file.

Comment: How do I declare main.js and CSS as a content script? Also, what do mean by substituting the local src?

Comment: Start with the [overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview), it explains what content scripts are and how to declare them. As for local src, it's right there in the link I gave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Solved by xOxxOm)

Declare main.js and css as a content script in manifest.json to make it run on web pages automatically. And then simply substitute local src for @font-family in the css file.